# How continue execute program after assertion in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am learning Exception in python and i have some doubt:

Can we use any name as error in raise?

like i have read when you use raise you have to define error type so can't i use any stringname as Error? like `SkienaError` or i have to keep in mind all the error types and have to use only those Error type names ?

```
    a=int(input())
if a!=10:
    raise SkienaError
else:
    print(a,"pp")
```

Second doubt is suppose i want user should input int but he input string so an assert pop up but i want program should continue without terminate and again ask for input until user give int type input , I don't want to use while loop here i want to know if it is possible with raise or assert in python ? like:

```
a=int(input())
assert type(a)==int
print(a,"hello")
```

So if user give str type input then is it possible program keep giving error and asking new input until input type is int.

Answer (score 10):

In order to make your own exception, you'll have to create it.

*e.g.*

```
class MyAppLookupError(LookupError):
'''raise this when there's a lookup error for my app'''
```

To continue execution after a thrown Exception, do it like this:

```
a = 5
try:
    assert a == 5
except AssertionError as e:
    print(e)
```

A `try` block will attempt to execute a block of code. If an exception occurs, it will execute the `except` block.

Comment: i tried what you said but failed check out what i am trying to do :  

http://paste.ofcode.org/brZxC42zRerVbmwSRpkrv4

Comment: `except error` is a syntax error. you want `except AssertionError`

Comment: i can't define anyname ? i have to use specially "AssertionError" as keyword ??

Comment: `assert` is a special keyword that raises an `Exception` of subctype `AssertionError`. You can write `except Exception` or `except AssertionError`. If you want to make your own, you'll have to write an `Exception` class for it.

Comment: ok sure i tried again what you said but its not asking again for int if i am giving str type input :  http://paste.ofcode.org/6SD7uwX6FNrvgppHxF5vEW

Comment: For that you'll want to use a while loop. I was just answering the questions about Exceptions.

Comment: ok i agree i have to use while but i want if assert occur then it throw error and execute rest or program , i don't want to write after the assert code in try block  i mean see this program :  http://paste.ofcode.org/8WDv4JFdyKtRJMA7nCBQxP      i want if assert occur then how can i print last line of print statement (at line 7) even after assertion occur ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the quesiton, but if you only want it to `print("mpw")` if the assert is `True`, just put `print("mpw")` below the `assert` in the `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

This might also work for your situation. The function `Assert()` prints a message `sTxt` in red color, if the Boolean input `bCond` is `False` and interpreter continues execution:

```
RED, END = '\033[91m', '\033[0m'
printRed = lambda sTxt: print(RED + sTxt + END)
Assert = lambda bCond=False, sTxt='': printRed(sTxt) if not bCond else None
```